# how to automatically add databaserows on daychange

Tags: mysql, events

I'm new to databases, so I have this table and I want to write some kind of script that adds or changes rows each day. Preferably exactly when the day changes.

The MySQL-Workbench apparently only supports lua & python scripts and I have no idea of the syntax.

I'm looking for something like

```
onDaychange(){
    SQL-query(INSERT ...)
    SQL-query(UPDATE ...)
}
```

Otherwise I'd have to run a permanent c# or java program on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You require MySQL `event` to run on a time basis.
You can schedule to call stored procedures as you like.

**Example**:

```
delimiter //
drop event if exists event_scheduling_sample;

create event if not exists event_scheduling_sample
--  on schedule every 86400 second starts 00:00:00
--  at timestamp( adddate( current_date, 1 ),'00:00:00' )
--  on schedule every 1 day starts current_timestamp ends current_timestamp + interval '5' day
--  on schedule every 1 day starts current_timestamp ends timestamp( current_date,'23:59:59' )
  on schedule every 1 day starts timestamp( current_date + 1, '00:00:01' )

  comment 'event scheduling sample'
  do
    call db_name.procedure_name();
;
//
delimiter ;
```

Refer to: [CREATE EVENT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html)

Default state of Event Scheduler is DISABLED.
You require to enable it by any of the following statements.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
SET @@global.event_scheduler = ON;
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
SET @@global.event_scheduler = 1;
```

When the Event Scheduler is ON, the event scheduler thread is listed in the output of `SHOW PROCESSLIST` as a daemon process, and its state is represented as shown here:

```
mysql> SHOW PROCESSLIST\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
     Id: 1
   User: root
   Host: localhost
     db: NULL
Command: Query
   Time: 0
  State: NULL
   Info: show processlist
*************************** 2. row ***************************
     Id: 2
   User: event_scheduler
   Host: localhost
     db: NULL
Command: Daemon
   Time: 3
  State: Waiting for next activation
   Info: NULL
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Once the Event Scheduler is set ON, you would see it working.

**Refer to** : [MySQL Event Scheduler Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-configuration.html)

Comment: ...or any programming language you like using the OS scheduler (at on MSWindows, cron on Linux/*nix). But in most cases this kind of scheduled batch processing is a consequence of poor dtabase design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cron Job for this script. Cron is the time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating systems. cron enables users to schedule jobs (commands or shell scripts) to run periodically at certain times or dates. It is commonly used to automate system maintenance or administration, though its general-purpose nature means that it can be used for other purposes, such as connecting to the Internet

**Cron File**

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (`text`,`date`) VALUES (testing','2012-6-25')");
//According to Date Condtion
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET `text`='testing2',`date`='2012-06-28'");
```